# How to identify in advance the key features from large data set where most of the data goes under one category using supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a very large data set extracted from machine(stream data) where most of the data fall under one category. if I train a classifier using the current data the accuracy will be very low. how to identify the key features in the giving data? also how can I measure the probability of some previous features in the time series?

Comment: What does the term "key features" mean to you?  And most likely any answer will depend on the classifier you are using, the structure of your data, and the goal of your system - none of which are specified.

Comment: The training data structure as follow: 
Window of 4 different values and target output
Ex:
At time t1:
V1=100, V2=200, V3=150, V4=400, target=-1
At time t2:
V1=102, V2=220,V3=170,V4=430,target=+1
And so on
In some cases one or more of the values V1,V2,V3 or V4 is the main feature that has/have the main affect in the target output for an online stream data (incremental)

Answer (score 0):

Typical methods for identifying important features include PCA and ICA.  However, even more valuable than these methods is having an understanding of the underlying system your data is representing.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without more information about the data structure. The best classification approach depends on the structure of your data and the aims of your analysis. There are some classifiers which can cope quite well with skewed data, I'd suggest that you have a look at some of the ensemble methods such as boosting and random or rotation forests.  Some of these classification methods, such as rotation forests, provide information about variable importance as part of the training process. If you just want to work out which features are most important, you could try using CART/random forests. If you want detailed help, though, I'd strongly suggest that you provide more information about your data structure and what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: the data structure as follow: